# Alfresco connector error

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share, document-management, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to do a connector to get a file. I receive the path of the file by args like :

```
var filePath = args["file"]
```

If I print this, I get the path correctly. But in the connector I have:

```
var connector = remote.connect("alfresco");
result = connector.get(args["file"])
```

and if I made this, this not recognise the path, the status is Error 500. I print the path and I paste like:

```
result = connector.get("/slingshot/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/f32afa20-4c73-4e6c-84e4-1c12d5964a95/txt.txt")
```

... But obvious, I want by args because I want for all the files.

What is my error? This is so strange for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future users that which may have the same problem, my problem was that args send the path with `""` like `"http://something"` and if we put `get("/slingshot/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/f32afa20-4c73-4e6c-84e4-1c12d5964a95/txt.txt")` don't have `""`. So, we can put the args on the string and make `string.substring(1,string.length-1)` to delete `""`.